# Can not create an iPhone xib file with Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, xcode6, interface-builder, xib

The checkbox to create a .xib file in Xcode 6 seems to be disabled. I can not find any way to enable it again. Does anybody know if this is possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FYI,  you can create xib file by follow.

[image]

Answer (score 64):

Make sure you didn't accidentally select the OS X Cocoa Class file type instead of iOS Cocoa Touch Class.

**Incorrect:**

[image: Screenshot of creating an OS X Cocoa Class]

**Correct:**

[image: Screenshot of creating an iOS Cocoa Touch Class]

Comment: great bit, that didn't stop me from accidentally creating it without the xib though

Answer (score 4):

Creating xib files in xcode 6 is,

First of all create empty project  as,
Go to-> File > New >Project, Then select IOS >Other > Empty  then Next
After that creating a xib file as,
Go to->File >New> File then IOS > Cocoa Touch Class and then NEXT 
Then select Viewcontroller and check for the **"Also create XIB file"** Then Next

This will create a empty project as well as xib file.

Comment: I think, you didn't select the subclass as UIViewController on that page. Try this one and then check for the XIB file. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I had encountered this problem. Below is fix for this :

1. Right click on files present in `Project Navigator` section.
2. Select `New File`.

   OR

   Select `File` from list of tab present in Xcode

   Select `New -> File`

   OR

   Simply press `cmd+N`
3. Choose template for your new file as `iOS` not OS X, tvOS or watchOS.

[image: Screenshot 1]

4. Select `Cocoa Touch Class` and then press `Next`
5. Enter `Class name` and select `subclass` of it.
6. Checkmark `Also create XIB file`.
7. Select device type and Language and then click Next
8. Click on `Create` and make sure that `Targets is selected.`

   [image: Screenshot 2]