# when I create a ViewController, "also create a xib" can't be seleted

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

[image]

last week, it work well. and there is nothing like "viewDidLoad" at the .m file.
My xCode version is 7.1.1. what's wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you selected iOS Source in the left part of the image

[image]

Comment: I was so stupid. tks

Answer (score 0):

Can you check? The issue might be you didn't select cocoa class from iOS.

Possible solution can be found here.

[Can not create an iPhone xib file with Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27596483/cant-create-a-iphone-xib-file-with-xcode-6)