# How to create a UIViewController subclass with .xib in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

[image]I am familiar with `Objective C`.
And learning `Swift` .

I want to reuse my `.xib` file designs with `Swift`.

But when i create a new file the `Create xib UI` is disabled .

Comment: see the below link and follow - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27596483/can-not-create-an-iphone-xib-file-with-xcode-6

Comment: Thanks  ,That is ok we can create separate- separate but my question is .... Can we make same as Objective C, create Both at same time or not ?

Comment: I don't get it...you say you already have an .xib file.  So why would you need to create one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason Xcode 7 has started defaulting to the OS X controls when I ask for a new file...

[image]

If you select this option and hit next then you cannot create a xib...

[image]

However, if you change to use the iOS files instead...

[image]

You then have the option to create a xib with your view controller...

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: this is called focus and accuracy :)

Answer (score 1):

by creating new file whatever in objective c or swift. you can create by attached screenshot

[image]

Comment: it is not working with Swift , You can check it .. in screen shot Image in question.

Comment: wait. i am adding new screenshot

Comment: In Xcode 7.2.1, I am not presented with that screen when creating a new swift source file.

Comment: than you need to create view controller.swift file than after create individual xib from user interface option

Comment: Did you create this project in Swift or not ?

Comment: of course swift. check screenshot. its not image editing .:)